# Renaming generated component/pipe

Tags: angular-cli

Is there any simple way to rename generated component/pipe.

Suppose that i have generated a component/pipe. I would like to rename later.

eg:

```
ng rename componentName newComponentName
```

Comment: Check this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49631019/4654957

Answer (score 0):

Currently cli is not supporting that feature, but is is one of [most wanted features](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/900) in angular cli.

So right now you have to manually rename `components/pipes/etc` but if you check that [comment](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/900#issuecomment-325947147), some one just created a custom tool that having functional you are looking for, but I haven't try that tool yet, so not sure if it is good enough.